# Will Scaffold.of ever find distant widget anestors?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to learn more about `BuildContext` and `Scaffold.of()`.

I understand that when you are displaying a `SnackBar` you often need to add a `Builder` to get the context 'under' the Scaffold you have added.

As such:

```
class MyScreen extends StatelessWidget {
   build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

        body: Builder(
          builder: (context) =>
           RaisedButton(
                child: Text('push me'),
                onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                    SnackBar(content: Text('this will work'))),
              ),
        ));
  }
}
```

My question is this: If `Scaffold.of()` gets the closest ancestor, shouldn't it usually eventually find something higher up the widget tree, e.g. the SplashScreen scaffold?
When we take away the builder and create this incorrect code:

```
class MyScreen extends StatelessWidget {
   build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

        body: RaisedButton(
                child: Text('push me'),
                onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                    SnackBar(content: Text('broken'))),
              ),
        ));
  }
}
```

then we get the standard error
`Scaffold.of() called with a context that does not contain a Scaffold.
I/flutter ( 7750)`
`No Scaffold ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to Scaffold.of().`

Even though there is no direct parent Scaffold in the `BuildContext`, how can no Scaffold ancestor be found at all (for example a Grandparent ancestor)? All the previous pages in my application had a scaffold, are they no longer in the widget tree?

I understand that if it found a Scaffold and rendered the SnackBar that we wouldn't be able to see it, but I still don't understand how it doesn't find one. Perhaps I've misunderstood what 'ancestor' means.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`BuildContext` represents the location of one specific widget in the widget tree.

As such, depending on what `BuildContext` you use, the call `Scaffold.of(context)` may behave differently.

In your following example:

```
class MyScreen extends StatelessWidget {
   build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
       body: RaisedButton(
         child: Text('push me'),
         onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
           SnackBar(content: Text('this will work'))),
       ),
     ),
   );
  }
}
```

Here, you are using the `BuildContext` of `MyScreen`. The issue is `MyScreen` is the widget that *creates* `Scaffold`. As such, `MyScreen` is an ancestor of `Scaffold` and cannot access it through `Scaffold.of(context)`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm still confused why `Scaffold.of(context)` isn't returning other Scaffolds from my application. If it returns the closest ancestor, and there is no scaffold inside MyScreen shouldn't it search further up the widget tree until it finds one?

Comment: No, because then it is not an _ancestor_. Widgets cannot access their descendants. It's simply impossible for them to do so

Comment: 1.Start Screen --> 2.Notes Screen --> 3.My Screen. I'm describing a situation like this, so `Start Screen` screen is an ancestor of `My Screen` not a descendent or am I missing something?

Comment: I think I have a solution from my colleague: whereas `Theme.of(context)` and `Navigator.of(context)` will search all the way up the widget tree until it finds a Theme or Navigator , `Scaffold.of(context)` only searches the _visible_ Scaffolds. Therefore it doesn't find the (non-visible) ancestor Scaffolds for example, the  StartScreen.

Comment: Wrong. This never happens, even with `Theme`/`Navigator`. Any of the `.of` pattern will *only* look into the parents of widgets. Never ever in the branches or descendants

Comment: I'm only talking about ancestors (parents, grandparents etc), going _up_ the tree. I agree it would never look in descendants.

Comment: Yes, but to look into other screen, it would have to go up _then_ down.